# Is there a more efficient way to calculate "step" division?

Tags: divisibility

I have a base value `16`, I need to divide it by the ratio `1.067` 6 times to reach the desired outcome value `10.84`, I'm currently doing this via:

```
16 / 1.067 / 1.067 / 1.067 / 1.067 / 1.067 / 1.067
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this calculation so I don't have to repeat the ratio multiple times? I was thinking something like this:

```
16 / (1.067 * 6)
```

But that gives me an incorrect outcome value of `2.49`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\frac {16}{1.067^6}$.

Comment: Very important to know in mathematics:
$$
a\times a = a^2, \qquad a\times a\times a = a^3 \quad \text{etc.}
$$